# How to join a table which is in another database in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, dblink

I have the join condition as below

```
Select ct.payment,pm.order   
from contract as ct  
left join payment_order as pm  
on ct.con_id=pm.id
```

Here the table payment_order is in another database 'payment'. How can i query this using dblink. please help.

Comment: Search for "executes a query" in the duplicate link.  It shows a great example of how to use dblink.

Comment: Thank you for the duplicate link... That solved my question